# Limit 10 firends in Facebook Send Dialog

Tags: facebook-apps

Is there any ways to allow user send message to only 10 friends in Facebook app?
I did not found any options for it in the document.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible (as of 2013-04). You can pre-populate the `To:` field with Facebook usernames, but the the user is presented with a send dialog where he can still edit/add/remove any friends (i.e. he can add more than 10 for example).